# How to modify "selected tab" bottom border color on TopTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm working on a react-native app using react-navigations `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`. I've read through the docs, but I cannot seem to find what props I need to modify to change the bottom border color of the active tab.

Does anyone have any advice?

[image: active tab bottom border]

FWIW here is my current Navigator code:

```
const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator()

function ProgressNavigator() {
  const themes = useThemes()

  return (
    <TopTab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: themes.lightBackground,
        },
        tabBarLabelStyle: {
          paddingTop: 10,
          fontSize: 14,
          fontWeight: "bold",
        },
        tabBarActiveTintColor: themes.secondary.color,
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#FFF",
      }}
    >
      <TopTab.Screen name="Table" component={ProgressTable} />
      <TopTab.Screen name="Chart" component={ProgressChart} />
    </TopTab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tabBarIndicatorStyle` to style an indicator. Below example sets label (and possible icon) and indicator to red.

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    tabBarActiveTintColor: 'red',
  }}>
...
</Tab.Navigator>
```